# What are near-minimal pairs

Tags: phonology, phonetics, phonemes, allophones, minimal-pairs

What are near-minimal pairs? How are they different from minimal pairs? Can Allophones occur in near-minimal pairs?

Comment: Please don't edit your question into something new after it's already been answered.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure. English "hit" and "hot" are near-minimal pairs, differing only in one phoneme, but the `/h/` is realized differently because of that (more like `[ç]` in the first one).

It's not always possible to find a true minimal pair to distinguish phonemes, so near-minimal pairs can sometimes be necessary. You just need to make sure that whatever differs between them isn't likely to be causing allophony.

Comment: You're using the term "phonemes can be in minimal pairs" wrong. Minimal pairs are one way we use to distinguish  phonemes -- the really important sounds that speakers pay attention to -- from allophones -- insignificant variations on phonemes that speakers ignore. If you write out the words in IPA (if you can't do that, learn), you'll see that /h/ has a different allophone before every vowel it precedes.

Comment: You are not using the term "phonemes can be in minimal pairs" at all, as far as I can see. Ninja edit?

Comment: I beg your pardon, "the /h/ is realized differently because of ..." what?

Comment: hit and hot are near minimal pairs?? The only difference is i and o. These are classic example of a minimal pair. hit=hɪt and hot=ˈhɑt [AmE] and hot=ˈhɒt [BrE]. Any of the vowels in these words make any two of them minimal pairs due only to the middle letter: hat, het, hit, hot, hut.

Comment: Do the vowels cause allophony (iotization) or did phonemic / phonetic changes cause the resemblence of one to the other? *hyttan, hittan* indicates a sense of palatal in OE already, but comparison to Norse *hitta* (etymonline) does not suggest breaking and \*hitjan (etymonline) is of uncertain origin. "classic example" my foot.

Comment: [The English phoneme /h/ has 13 or so allophones](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/4836/482) -- one for every different vowel it precedes.

Comment: @jlawler Yes, your post says: "What that means is that when an English speaker pronounces the words heat, hit, hate, hen, hat, hot, for instance, hey are pronouncing the phoneme strings /hit/, /hɪt/, /het/, /hɛn/, /hæt/, /hat/" Who cares about allophones here per se? What matters is that they are minimal pairs and not "near minimal pairs".

Comment: @Lambie I should clarify: a near-minimal pair for the difference between [ç] and [h]. They are of course a minimal pair for the difference between /ɪ/ and /ɔ/.

Comment: For the downvoters: this answers the original version of the question. The asker rewrote it into a new question after accepting this answer.

Answer (score 3):

A minimal pair is two distinct utterances which differ in the presence of exactly one surface phone, for example [væt] and [fæt]. The premise is that you first take note of various words as they are actually pronounced, so you have a record of the phones in the language. If you have a minimal pair, you have compelling evidence that the two phones derive from distinct phonemes, and are not allophones of a single phoneme.

A near-minimal pair is a pair of words which differ in more than one set of phones, where the number of differing phones is at least two, and hopefully not more than two. Near-minimal pairs are sometimes called on in cases where there are few or no minimal pairs to demonstrate the phonemic status of a phonic difference.

There is often chicken-egg confusion over the status of minimal pair in phonology. One does not know what the phonemes of a language are until one has performed a distributional analysis of phonetic segments, and that analysis can tell you that phonetic sounds X and Y are in complementary distribution (meaning that they can be treated as allophones of a single phoneme), or that X and Y are not in complementary distribution (are not allophones of a single phoneme). This then (supposedly) justifies positing certain allophonic rules, *if* the sounds have the requisite distribution. Sometimes, the evidence for complementary distribution is *almost* good enough, which is where near-minimal pairs become important (they can be used to establish phonemic contrast).

The crucial thing to remember is that one looks for minimal pairs in the phonetic record: it is not a hybrid of looking in the phonetic record but also looking at the abstract underlying form.

Everything that occurs in the phonetic record is an allophone (or, a phone). Allophone refers to the relation between a surface phone and whatever phoneme is is abstractly. [s] is an allophone of /s/, [p] and [pʰ] are allophones of /p/. The boring case is where a phoneme has only one allophone (pretty rare, actually). "Near minimal pair" is about the phonetic record, so it is always a relation between phones i.e. allophones. The reason for confusion over what a minimal pair is, is that this kind of automated distributional analysis has
fallen out of favor, even though we retain the old terminology.

Comment: Perhaps nitpicking, but I would disagree with much of the last paragraph here. Everything that occurs in the phonetic record is a phone, yes, but not necessarily an allophone; the statement that, “the boring case is where a phoneme has only one allophone” is oxymoronic. If a phoneme has only one surface form, it has _no allophones_ at all, only a single phone. An allophone is by definition _one of multiple possible_ phonetic forms (phones) of a phoneme.